# Unrecognized import path while fetching go package gin

Tags: go

Unrecognized import path while fetching go package gin. How do I resolve this issue

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
package gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1: dial tcp: i/o timeout)
package gopkg.in/yaml.v2: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp: i/o timeout)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to issue [#51](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/511) - which has a similar error - indicates that this is a problem with your network. Try again later or use some proxy, as suggested on the GitHub page, such as:

[Goproxy](https://github.com/ooclab/goproxy)

[Lantern](https://getlantern.org/)

Also, make sure you can `go get` other packages. It might be a package only problem or a 'global' one. In this case try the proxies above

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the command, and it works find.

Is your GOPATH correctly set? see [the documentation for more info.](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)